# Time zone settings and leakage of location

Tags: privacy

When you set up your clock in Linux systems and select a timezone:

- How easily can sites access this information? Can they do it through Javascript? Can they do it if Javascript is blocked?
- Where else is this information leaked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to retrieve information about the local system time and timezone from JavaScript. A script might fetch that and post it back to a server via Ajax or other measures. Your browser *may* also provide headers that include timestamps, so detection might be possible even when JavaScript is disabled.

It's impossible to iterate through all the potential ways that timezones and timestamps can be leaked, but here's a quick list:

- JavaScript
- Flash, Java, etc. plugins.
- HTTP headers
- Cache detection tricks
- Cookie tricks (e.g. setting a cookie to expire at a fixed date, then see when it expires)

All in all, though, I wouldn't be too worried. Timezones are a *very* weak identifier of location. I'd be much more worried about IP-based geolocation, ping triangulation, direct access to location services, etc.

Comment: I am happy that a security expert says it's a weak indicator. It still makes me nervous though. For example, isn't it a dead giveaway that someone is on a VPN? I would feel better if I could find an extension that spoofs timezone, but I can't even find that. (Apparently the issue is that there are many different Javascript functions that can access the system time.)

Comment: @felwithe It's not a giveaway at all. IP address blocks are *very* loosely associated with geographic location, and it's very common to find that users have a system time set to something that doesn't match their physical location (e.g. person travelling internationally with a device that doesn't have automatic timezone adjustment).

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the web browser, here are a few other places where timezone information may be leaked:

- Any emails you send from a local client will likely contain your timezone offset in the "Date" header
- Some programs will save timezone-specific information in their output files.  For instance, git will store your timezone offset any time you make a commit, and this is available to anybody reading the git repository.